# How to get N values along with pearson correlation?

Tags: r, correlation

I am using the code below to calculate the correlation map between two datasets.this code worked fine and I got the results which look like:![enter image description here]![enter image description here][1].

I would like also to get another map displaying how many pairs were used in calculation of each pixel so I get map of N a long with map of correlation.
as per Paul Hiemstra this function gave cor and N:

```
 cor_withN = function(...) {
      cor_obj = cor.test(...)
       print(sprintf("N = %s", cor_obj$parameter + 2))
       return(data.frame(cor = cor_obj$estimate, N = cor_obj$parameter + 2))
                          }
          cor_withN(runif(100), runif(100))
             [1] "N = 100"
                   cor   N
            cor 0.1718225 100
```

when I simply replaced cor by cor_withN I got this error:

```
    Error in cor.test.default(...) : not enough finite observations
```

How can I imply this function in my code to get two maps of correlation and N values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Error**

```
Error in cor.test.default(...) : not enough finite observations
```

According to `corr.test` source (http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats/R/cor.test.R) this error can appear in two cases:

1. You are using Pearson's correlation and have less than 3 finite pairs of observations.
2. You are using Kendall's or Spearman's correlation and have less than 2 pairs.

Indeed, `cor.test(c(1,2), c(2,3))` causes exactly the same error, while `cor(c(1,2), c(2,3))` gives an answer.

Note, that `cor.test` uses `complete.cases(x,y)` for calculations. So, look into your data - probably there are not enough pairs somewhere.

**2. Function**

`cor` returns `numeric` value, your function `corr_withN` returns `data.frame`. So, it doesn't look like you can simply *replace* one by another.

As I understand you need just a matrix of size `1440x720` which will be plotted over the map. In this case you can just use `cor` for the first plot, and simple function returning the number of pairs used to calculate correlation for the second. The function itself can be as simple as:

```
cor_withN <- function(...) {
  cor.test(...)$parameter+2
}
```

**UPDATE: After comment**

If `cor_withN` must return `NA` when there are less than 3 pairs it should be modified:

```
cor_withN <- function(...) {
  res <- try(cor.test(...)$parameter+2, silent=TRUE)
  ifelse(class(res)=="try-error", NA, res)
}
```

This function tries to compute correlation and, if it fails, returns `NA` or number of pairs otherwise.